# Non-linear regression produces different results for each run

Tags: matlab, non-linear-regression, probability-density

I have been trying to fit a power-law distribution: `ns ~ s^-a` `(where ns is the probability density function; s is the empirical observation; and a is the scaling exponent)` to my empirical data (see link) using MATLAB's fit function. However, I am having problems getting a reproducible solution. When I do not specify a startpoint, I get different results for each run -- in spite of the fact that I'm using the same dataset. Then, when I do specify a startpoint, the function gives me the same result as my specified startpoint. Also, the issue remains regardless of whether I specify an algorithm such as the Levenberg-marquardt, or if I used the default algorithm. My codes are as follows:

```
clc; clear; close all;

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Load data
[data, ~, ~] = xlsread('myDataset.xlsx',1,'A:A'); 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Histogram plot 
data = sort(data);
[y, edges] = histcounts(data, 100000, 'Normalization','pdf');
edges = edges(2:end) - (edges(2)-edges(1))/2;
figure;
scatter(edges, y, 4, 'ro', 'Markerfacecolor', 'r');
hold on;
box on;

edges = edges';
y = y';

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Specify input parameters
%(1): cut-off value
xmin = 1*10^5; 
%(2): x-values after cut-off
x    = edges(edges>=xmin);
ind  = find(edges>=xmin,1,'first');
%(3): y-values after cut-off
y([1:ind-1]) = [];

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% fit power-law model
f = fittype('b*x.^-a'); 
fModel = fit(x, y, f, 'Algorithm','levenberg-marquardt'); 
coeffs = coeffvalues(fModel);
plot(fModel,'b--')

set(gca, 'xscale','log', 'yscale','log')
xlabel('s', 'fontsize',8)
ylabel('ns', 'fontsize',8)
```

The value of `a` is said to be around `2.189`. Although I may not get this exact value - as it will depend on the dataset, I however expect to at least get values in the range of about `1.5 - 2`.

I do appreciate any help, suggestions, or references that will be useful in solving the problem. Please kindly see link the following link for the empirical data. https://gofile.io/?c=EoEW7k

Many thanks.

Comment: What you describe is the expected behaviour. No algorithm will give you a perfect answer. Maybe you just need to increase the iterations, or tighten the tolerance parameters, but basically numerically speaking, and even more in a non-linear case, getting the same answer all the times is impossible. There is quite a lot of research on finding a good initial condition to your problem before optimization because of this. Generally problem-specific heuristics

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to fit your data to a power law distribution, `y=ax^b`, you should check [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingPowerLaw.html) or [this](https://archive.lib.msu.edu/crcmath/math/math/l/l144.htm) link, as they provided a closed form solution for the `a` and `b` terms .

The reasoning for the suitability of the equations, or an explanation for 'where does it come from' comes from the formulas utilized to obtain a least squares fitting for the linear regression.

If you have an equation of the form `y=ax+b`, you can find `a` and `b` from a least squares linear regression. If you have a power law, `y=ax^b`. log both sides and use the [logarithm properties](https://www.rapidtables.com/math/algebra/Logarithm.html) to obtain:

`y=ax^b`→ `log(y)=log(ax^b)`→ `log(y)=log(a)+blog(x)`→`Y=A+BX`→**Linear equation**

You can use the linear regression formulas to `log(x)` and `log(y)` to obtain `a` and `b`. This avoids the use of a numerical method to obtain the regression of the nonlinear fit.

MATLAB built-in function [fit](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html) solves the optimization problem of least squares fit - it tries to minimize the sum of the squares of the residuals. If your problem is nonlinear, the algorithm relies on a good initial estimative. Different initial estimatives may produce different results. That is the problem with nonlinear problems and optmizations.

As a rule of thumb, every time you have to do a fit, if your problem is not linear, the first step you should try is to see if you can linearize your equation. If you can, as is the case here, you have closed form solutions for the coefficients and don't need to rely on numerical methods and good/poor initial estimates.

Comment: Thank you @Thales. I have tried the log-transformation but I don't get any meaningful solution. However, when I use those solutions as startpoints (see: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/155717-how-to-select-proper-parameters-for-opt-startpoint), I get reasonable results **IF** I remove the cut-off restriction (i.e. xmin) on the data. This means that the main issue lies in the cut-off value that I chose. Thus, going forward, I need to optimize the cut-off value (or tolerance if you like) in line with **Ander Biguri's** suggestion.